# Matching closest longitude/latitude

Tags: mysql, geospatial, latitude-longitude

Using Maxmind's GeoIP software, we can narrow down the LONG/LAT of an IP address to relative accuracy within 25 miles around 80% of the time.

Now, we don't want to use any of the other information provided by MaxMind, because there are a lot of discrepancies between feature names, i.e., cities, to perform a look up. We plan on attempting such a look up if other methods fail to locate a feature, but for performance reasons, look ups on floats are much faster than strings.

Now, I'm a little clueless on how we can find the closest matching LAT/LONG given from Maxmind to our database. The problem is, our datbase features has a much higher precision compared to that of Maxmind, therefore a straight comparison might not be effective. If we try applying a ROUND() to the column during query, that will obviously be really slow.

Given the following data, would the fastest way simply be something like

LONG 79.93213
LAT 39.13111

```
SELECT `feature_name` FROM `geo_features`
WHERE long BETWEEN 79.93 AND 79.79.94
AND lat BETWEEN 39.13 AND 39.14
```

Can anyone thing of an elegant solution that will be blazing fast? I know there are some new spatial storage types in MySQL 5, perhaps anyone can provide a solution beyond the blinders I've seem to put up on myself.

Comment: [This post](http://lists.mysql.com/mysql/204782) on mysql's site may be of help (specifically mentions lat/long coordinates).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The elegant (**more accurate**) way of doing this (*but not blazing fast*)

```
// Closest within radius of 25 Miles
// 37, -122 are your current coordinates
// To search by kilometers instead of miles, replace 3959 with 6371
SELECT feature_name, 
 ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians(37) ) * cos( radians( lat ) ) 
  * cos( radians( long ) - radians(-122) ) + sin( radians(37) ) 
  * sin( radians( lat ) ) ) ) AS distance 
FROM geo_features HAVING distance < 25 
ORDER BY distance LIMIT 1;
```

**Edit**

This is [Haversine formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haversine_formula) for calculating circular distance from geo-coordinates. Here are some implementation of this formula in [different platforms](http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html)

```
R = earth’s radius (mean radius = 6,371km)
Δlat = lat2− lat1
Δlong = long2− long1
a = sin²(Δlat/2) + cos(lat1).cos(lat2).sin²(Δlong/2)
c = 2.atan2(√a, √(1−a))
d = R.c
// Note that angles need to be in radians to pass to Trigonometric functions
```

Comment: We've already implemented a solution, similar to what I already posted, but using a subset of our 2.5M feature db into something more manageable. However, since this is what I kind of asked for, if you could please explain the constants you've used, I will accept your answer. Thanks.

Comment: Also, it seems alot of these values can be pre-calculated. Is there a reason why you are doing it this way?