# Find all values from X within Y radius from a given location (longitude,latitude)

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, rails-geocoder

I have a model named **Offering** and **User**

user has_many offerings.

Every offering has two fields `long`, `lat` which contains the longitude latitude of the offering, where it is created.

Suppose, A user's location is 2.323, -32.344. Now I want to show him the offerings which is within 10 miles radius from his location.

I'm using MySQL, engine= INNODB

Have any idea?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Matching closest longitude/latitude](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4982125/matching-closest-longitude-latitude)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Geocoder does provide such kind of scopes:

```
# venues within 10 miles of 'Omaha, NE, US'
Offering.near('Omaha, NE, US', 10)    

# venues within 10 miles of [40.71, 100.23]
Offering.near([40.71, 100.23], 10)
```

[Doc here](https://github.com/alexreisner/geocoder#location-aware-database-queries)